# Graphite synthesize install quits with error - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7a0tqlu_/cryptography/

Tags: graphite

I am attempting to install Graphite using the "synthesize" manually. I downloaded the zip file from github and ran the "sudo ./install"command.

Running this on a VM with: "Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS" as required.

The installation runs and after a short while ends with the following errors:
(below is the end of the run with the errors)

File "/tmp/pip-build-7a0tqlu_/cryptography/setup.py", line 14, in 
from setuptools_rust import RustExtension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'

```
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE==========================
        If you are seeing an error here please try the following to
        successfully install cryptography:

        Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
        users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE==========================


----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7a0tqlu_/cryptography/

The python versions on the system are the following:

```
  Pip -V 
  pip 20.3.4 from /home/muser1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

  pip3 -V
  pip 21.3.1 from /home/muser1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Note: when the install script runs, it seems to run eventually pic up python3. Not sure why since the main python version is python2 and running "python" manually invokes python 2.7

Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

**----UPDATE-----------------**

**@phd** -- Thanks for links, They helped move the install along.
Now that I'm past the pip and rust errors, now I get the following:

**--------------**

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six-1.16.0-py3.6.egg
Finished processing dependencies for whisper==1.1.7

- cd ../carbon
- git checkout 1.1.7
  Note: checking out '1.1.7'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

git checkout -b

HEAD is now at 56250f5 Release 1.1.7

- pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  Collecting whisper
  Cloning git://github.com/graphite-project/whisper.git to /tmp/pip-install-l9ng7ab3/whisper_a5185fddc88f4dd9886e45996fe05ac0
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none -q git://github.com/graphite-project/whisper.git /tmp/pip-install-l9ng7ab3/whisper_a5185fddc88f4dd9886e45996fe05ac0
  fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
  github.com[0: 140.82.112.4]: errno=Connection timed out

WARNING: Discarding git+git://github.com/graphite-project/whisper.git#egg=whisper. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone --filter=blob:none -q git://github.com/graphite-project/whisper.git /tmp/pip-install-l9ng7ab3/whisper_a5185fddc88f4dd9886e45996fe05ac0 Check the logs for full command output.
Collecting Twisted>=13.2.0
Using cached Twisted-22.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement whisper (unavailable) (from versions: 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.9.7, 0.9.8, 0.9.9, 0.9.10, 0.9.11, 0.9.12, 0.9.13, 0.9.14, 0.9.15, 0.9.16, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.1.10)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for whisper (unavailable)

**-------------**

Any additional help would be appreciated with the whisper errors listed above.

Thanks!

** Nope -- question was not answered but was closed as a duplicate automatically**

** Graphite seems to be unsupported and dead... Moving on to another tool that is still actively being developed and simpler to install **

** Now you can close this. **

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+No+module+named+setuptools_rust

Comment: To install https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/ you need Rust and `setuptools_rust`. See https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#rust